# RewriteRule not working "duplicate home dir"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite specific URL:

> http://www.example.com/index.php

to be

> http://www.example.com/Encode

but I recieve

> The requested URL /encrypo/encrypo/test/index.php was not found on
>   this server.

I don't know why "encrypo" directory appear twice in requested URL.

my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule     ^Encode/?$      index.php       [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Encode$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Could you explain what your answer does and why the question's code was wrong?